# Repeat a function forever

Tags: jquery

With the following I call a function. The function waits, then fades out an image, waits, then fades it back in.

```
function fadeOut() {
  $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
  });
}
fadeOut();
```

How can I make this function repeat forever? Can I put a line of code before the closing } of the fadeOut function that makes it start from the beginning again?

UPDATE - Here is my Drupal site. It seems the code should work. http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/t/

And here is my exact code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() > 960) {
    function fadeOutFunc() {
      $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeIn(500,fadeOutFunc);
      });
    }

    fadeOutFunc();
    // jQuery('.image-list .bottom').css('opacity','0.6');
  }    
});
```

Comment: could probably use `setInterval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply tell it to call itself when the `fadeIn` is over. Fortunately, jQuery has built-in support for this, which you are already using to fade in after fading out:

```
function fadeOut() {
    $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeIn(500,fadeOut); // <-- see the tiny change?
    });
}

fadeOut();
```

edit: it occurs to me that you can use more of jQuery's syntax to simplify this a little:

```
function fadeOut() {
    $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeOut(500).delay(5000).fadeIn(500,fadeOut);
}
fadeOut();
```

Comment: @Blender why would he? The stack unrolls each time a synchronous block completes - what's left is a bunch of pending timeouts.

Comment: @Blender are you sure? This doesn't have nested scope, so it shouldn't… jQuery's callback must be event driven at a low level so this should be fine.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yep, it dies on me at 900 iterations. Try it out by removing the `.delay()` calls and setting the animation speeds to `0`.

Comment: @Blender by doing that you have removed the events from the loop entirely, so in that case yes, it will die (jQuery will be taking shortcuts and executing the callbacks within the same scope)

Comment: @Dave: Oh, that's probably why. Ignore me.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, if fades out and in but then stops.

Comment: @jdln can you make a simplified jsfiddle?

Comment: is there a reason to not use setInterval - it seems to be exactly what it was made for. Not questioning just curious.

Comment: @jdln here's a quick test-case which shows that this method works: http://jsfiddle.net/EbZJN/ if it isn't working for you it's likely because there's something more complicated going on which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @timpone see Jan Dvorak's comment on Afzaal's answer.

Comment: @timpone if something delays, the jQuery queue will build up. Imagine pouring water into a funnel. Either the throughput will be reduced compared to the funnel maximum, or the funnel will overflow. Better solution: pour some water into the funnel each time it's empty - you'll maximise the throughput and the funnel won't overflow.

Comment: Here is my site (built with Drupal) which its not working for. http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/t/ I know its not an issue with your code as the fiddle works, but any help would still be much appreciated.

Comment: @jdln at a guess, maybe you're queuing too much on jQuery's animation queue elsewhere? Your site is very complex and uses a lot of libraries. Best bet is to put a load of logging there and check which bits aren't firing as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would have used setInterval:

```
setInterval(function fadeOut() {
    $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('img.my-image').delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
    });
}, 1000);
```

This will load the function every 1 sec as 1000 milliseconds are 1 second. And it won't stop!

**Edit:** You can use any much seconds for your job. Just use them as second_count * 1000 as 2*1000 or 2000 for 2 seconds.

Well that's not the issue Jan Dovark, you can try using this code:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
```

So the setInterval works when the window tab is in focus!

Comment: this is probably the tidier solution, but you need to use an interval of 11000 not 1000. For similar reasons, it might be harder to maintain. Not sure why you got downvoted though.

Comment: The animation you're enqueuing takes 11 seconds if all goes well, so you shouldn't be enquing it once per second or two. Even if you enqueue it once per 11 seconds, if the browser hiccups and takes its time to call an important timeout, stuff will start queuing up - probably nothing serious, but still unclean.

Comment: Downvoted because it's a fragile solution. If the interval is shorter than the animation, the jQuery animation queue will start growing. If the interval is longer, it might be hard to debug the cause of a pause. Each time you change the timing inside the function, you have to propagate the change to the interval. It's easy to forget.

Comment: @Dave even if you get the timing set up correctly, if something delays (it will), the jQuery queue will build up. Imagine pouring water into a funnel. Either the throughput will be reduced compared to the funnel maximum, or the funnel will overflow. Better solution: pour some water into the funnel each time it's empty - you'll maximise the throughput and the funnel won't overflow.

Comment: using this would minimize the issue brother `$(window).focus(function() {` so the function runs only when the window is in focus.

Comment: How exactly would you use `$(window).focus(function() {`? Set off another interval each time the window is bringed into focus? Unless you also clear the interval each time the window is blurred, you will _worsen_ the issue, not _lessen_ it. But, I was not talking about what happens when you lose focus. What I meant is that each time the computer thrashes for 11 seconds (assuming the interval was set correctly, which it _still_ isn't) the animation queue perpetually grows by one entry. What's worse, when it does, different pieces of the animation will start being enqueued in the wrong order.

Comment: If the interval is set too short (which it _still_ is), the animation queue will grow by ten entries each eleven seconds. Remember the `delay`s are a part of the animation. Whymarrh's answer doesn't have the issue even if his animation queue grows much faster because he enqueues all four steps at the same time, which means that even if the queue grows abysmally, the animation steps don't exchange each other. At the time of writing, the animation queue in his pen already has 180 000  entries!

Comment: I've set up a fiddle with your code. With the correct timing, it still eventually breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/E2RQ9/. If the timing is too short, it gets arhythmia much sooner: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/E2RQ9/1/. If we log when the events get fired, we get some very interesting numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/E2RQ9/3/ If that is not a proof, please observe the `$("img").queue().length`. Even if not as appaling as in  Whymarrh's case, the number is still pretty scary. Hint: you'll have to clean up the mess when you ever want to stop the animation and do something else with the elem.